# what should i do to run this play again button, app crashes when its pressed(making a tic tac toe game)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, tic-tac-toe

plz help me out in this problem
   i tried many changes that were suggested in android studio
   basically the problem occurs in playAgain function
   it crashes but it shold clear the images im the imageviews

> main activity

```
    package com.example.xo;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.GridLayout;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;


        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            0=o,1=x,2=empty

            int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};

            int[][] winningPositions = {{0,1,2} ,{3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7} ,{2,5,8} ,{0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};

            int activePlayer = 0;

            boolean gameActive = true;

            public void dropIn(View view) {

            ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

            int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

            if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameActive) {

                gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

                counter.setTranslationY(-1500);

                if (activePlayer == 0) {

                    counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);

                    activePlayer = 1;

                } else {

                    counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);

                    activePlayer = 0;

                }

                counter.animate().translationYBy(1500).setDuration(300);

                for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {

                    if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] && gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] && gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {

                        gameActive = false;

                        String winner = "";

                        if (activePlayer == 1) {

                            winner = "O";
                        } else {
                            winner = "X";
                        }


                        Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);

                        TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);

                        winnerTextView.setText(winner + " Won");

                        playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                }

            }
        }


            public void playAgain (View view){

                Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);

                TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);

                playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                GridLayout gridLayout1 = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout1);

                for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout1.getChildCount(); i++) {

                    ImageView counter = (ImageView) gridLayout1.getChildAt(i);



                    counter.setImageResource(0);

                }

                for (int i=0; i<gameState.length; i++) {

                    gameState[i] = 2;
                }



                activePlayer = 0;

                gameActive = true;
            }


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

> ## Activity main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="409dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/b"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="3">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="137dp"
            android:layout_height="143dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="5"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="1" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="127dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="4"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:tag="3"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="117dp"
            android:layout_height="127dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:tag="1"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="132dp"
            android:layout_height="129dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="2"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="122dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="6"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="131dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="7"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="137dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="8"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="127dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:tag="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="0" />


    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="276dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="276dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:onClick="playAgain"
        android:text="@string/play_again"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/winnerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> **> > > Logcat
>
> > > ```
> > > 2019-10-18 23:32:30.422 13338-13338/com.example.xo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> > >     Process: com.example.xo, PID: 13338
> > >     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
> > >         at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
> > >         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
> > >         at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
> > >         at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
> > >         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
> > >         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> > >         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> > >         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> > >         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
> > >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> > >         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> > >         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
> > >      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> > >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> > >         at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
> > >         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
> > >         at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
> > >         at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
> > >         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
> > >         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
> > >         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
> > >         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
> > >         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
> > >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> > >         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
> > >         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
> > >      Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to
> > > ```
> > >
> > > android.widget.GridLayout
> > >                   at com.example.xo.MainActivity.playAgain(MainActivity.java:96)
> > >                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> > >                   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
> > >                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
> > >                   at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
> > >                   at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
> > >                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
> > >                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
> > >                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
> > >                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
> > >                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
> > >                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> > >                   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
> > >                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
> > >           2019-10-18 23:32:30.438 13338-13338/com.example.xo I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13338 SIG:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridLayout you are using in xml is different from gridlayout you import in your java class. Both must be same. The error is **java.lang.ClassCastException** and the reason for error is in your xml you are using **androidx gridlayout** and in your java class, you are using **android gridlayout**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i checked but didnt find the different gridlayout in java class , can you plz tell me in which line the edit is to done.

Comment: that onClick method when the playAgain button is crashing the app

Comment: that button when pressed prints hi in logcat perfectly so the button is perfect i think

Comment: androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout gridLayout =  findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

Comment: i changed this one and everything works fine thanks for ut guidance brother

Answer (score 0):

You will find the below answer useful;

import androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout

In the top page of your MainActivity.java

Edit the existing

"import.android.widget.GridLayout "

as

"import androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout"